# Chrome Extension InstanceID getToken

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension that can receive FCM push messages. After going through the docs I assume that I need to use the InstanceID API to generate a token from my extension and use that when pushing FCM messages to the extension.

To do this I used the following code  -

```
chrome.instanceID.getToken({authorizedEntity: "my-project-ID", scope: "GCM"}, callback);
```

This is the runtime error that I received - `{message: "Function was called with invalid parameters."}`

Slightly confused here now.

Comment: Odd. Are you positive that the value of `authorizedEntity` is equal to the Sender ID visible in your Firebase Project? Also, try using `"FCM"` as the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Even the documentation instructing to use project ID it is wrong. You need use the [project number](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#determine_the_id_number_of_a_standard) instead.

```
chrome.instanceID.getToken(
    {
        authorizedEntity: '123456789' /* project number here */, 
        scope: 'GCM',
    }, 
    token => console.log(token)
)
```